# SQL Server R multiple result sets

Tags: sql-server, r, datatable, dataset, analytics

Is it possible to get more than one table as a result from executing R script with SQL Server 2016+? Let's take a random simple example from the internet (no need to post mine to not overcomplicate the issue):

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'R',
  @script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',
  @input_data_1 =N'SELECT 1 AS hello'
  WITH RESULT SETS (([hello] int not null));
```

as posted in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-code-in-transact-sql-quickstart).

Here the result is returned as a single table. Let's say I do various calculations with the data and now I want to return multiple tables as a result.

For example:

```
a<-InputDataSet

b<-InputDataSet + 5
```

These would return two different tables as results. Now I cannot figure any nice way to return the data in two separate tables as it only returns one table. Obviously, I can return it like this:

```
OutputDataSet<-data.frame(a, b)
```

But dealing with different functions and different data it soon becomes quite a hassle. For example I use a function `lm`. Now one dataset would be calculated estimated values and another would be the coefficients of each column participating in the equation. Again, of course I can join these two datatables and deal with them later, but the output result becomes colossal in many cases.

The parameters to the procedure look like: `..., @output_data_1_name`, but there is no `@output_data_2_name`, etc. thus I do not see a way. Maybe it is possible to create the `OutputDataSet` so it holds multiple tables? If so - I am not aware of such way in R due to my lack of experience with it.

**tldr;** is it possible to return multiple result sets or my only solution is to manually construct the output in R code so I would always get one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Microsoft Documentation it is at the moment not possible to return more than one table. It states on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-working-with-inputs-and-outputs):

> Only one input dataset can be passed as a parameter, and you can
>   return only one dataset.

However, you can return additional single variables, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-create-a-predictive-model-r):

> Generally, the output of R from the stored procedure
>   sp_execute_external_script is limited to a single data frame. (This
>   limitation might be removed in future.)
>
> However, you can return outputs of other types, such as scalars, in
>   addition to the data frame.

There is also an example given on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I do believe this will be sufficient enough. Thank you very much for the effort on your research.

Comment: Thanks too from me. I've read quite a lot around this issue - for both the input and output datasets - and had completely missed the trick for returning additional scalar outputs. Cheers for pointing that link out!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tables (`data.frame` or `data.table`) can be returned in the form of a block matrix. `data.table::rbindlist(L, fill = T)` will create a block matrix out of a list of `L` of `data.frame` or `data.table`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp153462
CREATE TABLE temp153462
              ([speed] int NULL,
               [dist] int NULL,
               [sepal_length] float NULL,
               [sepal_width] float NULL,
               [petal_length] float NULL,
               [petal_width] float NULL,
               [species] nvarchar(20) NULL)
insert into temp153462

exec sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'R', 
@script = N'library(data.table)            
            library(datasets)
            print(cars)
            print(iris)
            OutputDataSet <- rbindlist(list(cars, iris), fill = T)
            print(OutputDataSet)'
SELECT speed, dist FROM temp153462 WHERE speed is not NULL
SELECT sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width FROM temp153462 WHERE sepal_width is not NULL
```

This does require the `data.table` package, which I recommend for other reasons.

There is also `plyr::rbind.fill()` which does something similar.